# Error when binding iOS delegate in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, binding, xamarin

I'm trying to port the TapForTap iOS SDK to my Monotouch C# application.

Using the documentation and a binding generator I created the following binding ApiDefintion:

```
namespace TapForTap {

[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface TapForTap {
    [...]
    [Static]
    [Export ("initializeWithAPIKey:")]
    void InitializeWithAPIKey (string key);
}

[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
[Model]
interface TapForTapAdViewDelegate {
    [Abstract]
    [Export ("rootViewController")]
    UIViewController RootViewController ();

    [...]
}

[BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
interface TapForTapAdView {
    [Static]
    [Export ("initWithFrame:delegate:")]
    NSObject Init (RectangleF frame, TapForTapAdViewDelegate d);

    [Export ("loadAds")]
    void LoadAds ();

    [Export ("stopLoadingAds")]
    void StopLoadingAds ();

            [...]
}
}
```

In my project I've created a class TapForTapDelegate implementing TapForTapAdViewDelegate.

```
public partial class TapForTapAdDelegate : TapForTapAdViewDelegate {
    public override UIViewController RootViewController () {
        return Application.mainViewController;
    }

    [...]
}
```

The problem is that I'm really not sure if I implemented the initWithFrame:delegate: function correctly.

Whenever I try to use the following code I get `NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: +[TapForTapAdView initWithFrame:delegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x36dac4`

```
bannerAd = (TapForTapAdView) TapForTapAdView.Init (new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, y, 320, 50), new TapForTapAdDelegate());
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried since hours and haven't found any solution.
I'm used to Java, not C# and Objective-C ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that init* methods are bound as C# constructors.

Try this:

```
[BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
interface TapForTapAdView {
    [Export ("initWithFrame:delegate:")]
    IntPtr Constructor (RectangleF frame, TapForTapAdViewDelegate d);

    ...
}
```

[Here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries) is more documentation about how to bind Objective-C libraries in Xamarin.iOS. In particular see section [3.3 Binding Constructors](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries#3.3.binding-constructors).